# Bayes Theorem Number of Girls in Set of Children Problem

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

I am working through re-learning stats and currently on Bayes Theorem.
The following question has me stumped from an intuitive point of view:

Suppose a family has 3 children. If at least 2 of the 3 children are girls, what is the probability that all 3 children are girls?

If 2/3 of the children are girls, my mind sees only one remaining probability to calculate, the probability that the 3rd child is a girl, which in my mind is 50%. Am I framing the question wrong or missing a different piece of this puzzle?

Comment: How would you frame it using Bayes' rule?$$P(\text{girls =3 | at least 2 girls}) = \dots ?$$

Comment: Your framing is [not necessarily wrong](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) depending on how you interpret 'at least 2 of the 3 children are girls'.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be the number of girls the family has (out of three children). The probability we need to calculate is
$$P(G=3|G\geq 2)=\frac{P(G=3\cap G\geq 2)}{P(G\geq 2)}=\frac{P(G=3)}{P(G\geq 2)}$$

$P(G=3)=P(ggg)=1/2\times1/2\times1/2=1/8$

And,

$P(G\geq2)=P(ggb)+P(gbg)+P(bgg)+P(ggg)=4/8$

So, the asked probability is $\frac{1/8}{4/8}=1/4$